# Java 8 + Android

Tags: java, android

É possível utilizar todo o potencial da API Java 8 (consultas lambda e etc) em sistemas Android?

Se sim, já vale a pena fazer a migração?

Comment: O projeto retrolambda é um bom ponto de partida, mas não inclui todo o API Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não.

Android não usa a JDK da Oracle, nem é exatamente um port dela. Portanto, não, não há como usar "Java 8" no Android.
Lembre-se que a **maioria** das features do JDK7 foram apenas agora suportadas no Android (4.4).

Como mencionado pelo luiscubal, o que você pode fazer é usar certas features do Java 8 no seu aplicativo Android, usando o retrolambda, por exemplo.

Se um dia teremos esses recursos incorporados no Android, só o tempo dirá. Por enquanto, não há planos públicos para tal.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que sim, mas eu não recomendo fazer isso, pois ainda tem muitos usuários que devem ainda estar usando Java 7. É sempre bom manter seu app funcionando na atual e a anterior versão do Java.

Answer (score 1):

Não.

Isso é porque o Android não usa o JDK da Oracle, oficial, como já dito. Mas, pelo que eu sei, usa a biblioteca de classes Apache Harmony e também implementa um ambiente de execução totalmente diferente do ambiente de execução Java tradicional: A DVM é uma máquina virtual que nem sequer segue a especificação da Sun/Oracle pra máquinas virtuais Java.

Todo o universo do Android não acompanha a evolução do Java tradicional, portanto, o Android não tem ainda ou talvez nunca tenha as novidades do Java 8.